How to solve a matrix equation involving Rank
Given that the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.
I want to solve for the matrix $B= \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & d \end{bmatrix}$ given that:
$$Rank[A]=Rank[\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}]$$
Both $A$ and $B$ are defined mod 3.
I have tried using LinearSolve and Solve for example:
matrixA= {{0,1,1,1},{1,2,1,2}}
matrixAB= {{0,1,1,1},{1,2,1,2},{a,0,0,0},{0,b,0,0},{0,0,c,0},{0,0,0,d}}
LinearSolve[MatrixRank[A]==MatrixRank[matrixAB],{a,b,c,d,e}]

but LinearSolve doesn't seem to really account for the MatrixRank function being part of the equation?
I have seen a similar question asked here but despite numerous attempts I have not managed to translate their methodology to this question in 5 unknown variables.

Rank isn't a function, is it?

Since the rank of a matrix is not a linear function of the matrix elements, LinearSolve[] is not appropriate.

The rank of matrix A is: 2. Therefore, B can not increase the rank of AB. It follows that the rows of B must be linear combinations of rows of A. However, as B is diagonal, there is at most only one non zero element in each. And from the rows of A we can only generate a row with at most 1 element different from zero by the  null combination:
{0,0}.A

Therefore:
sol= matrixAB /. {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 0}

and:
 Rank[sol]

2


What if I had something that could potentially increase the rank. Say if B was $((0,b,c,d),(a,0,c,2d))$?

I know that say for example if $a=b=c=d=2$, then the rank of matrixAB with new $B$ above would still be $2$, so then this should be a solution.

In addition to Daniel Huber's answer, you can perform brute-force search:
cases = Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> #] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 4]; Short[cases, 5]


Select[cases, (MatrixRank[matrixAB /. #, Modulus -> 3] == 2) &]

(* {{a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 0}} *)

